# How can I tell which difficulty I'm playing?

Tags: achievements, ps3, tomb-raider-anniversary

I was playing Tomb Raider Anniversary on the PS3 (the HD trilogy version), I played the game on the Hard difficulty and reached the Greece's boss. I quit the game before finishing the boss and played a level by replaying it and chose the Easy difficulty. Afterwards I came back to my save, finished the boss and continued playing through the game.

When I finished the game though, I didn't get the trophy *Hard Enough* for completing the game on hard (I did get the *Sweet Victory* trophy for completing the game), which led me to believe my one level as easy changed the difficulty for the rest of my game.

No I face a tough situation, I can replay each levels from the last Greece level onwards on hard, but I don't know if playing the levels individually counts, and the game boots you back to the main menu after each level which leads me to question whether it really does. Another option I have is loading my last save before the one I quit to replay a level and complete the game again from that point onwards, but after loading that save I can't really tell what difficulty it's set to.

Is there a way to know which levels I completed on the hard difficulty? Is there a way to tell if my loaded save is on hard? (Perhaps by the damage enemies do). Is there a sure way to get the trophy *without* deleting my save and starting the game again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered and I managed to solve the issue myself, I'll post my solution.

I replayed each level from the last Greece level till the end of the game by choosing *Replay Level* from the menu and picking the hard difficulty. After completing the final boss the *Tough Enough* trophy unlocked.

What happens, according to to other people's experience is that if during your hard story mode playthrough you replay a level or do a time trial, your auto save lowers its difficulty to Medium, you have no way to know that but by looking at the difficulty level the game offers you when choosing to replay a level  after you've loaded your main save (it offers the last played difficulty). Since I knew where my game changed difficulty, I was able to replay only the levels I messed.

I hope my experience helps others with this issue.